# ¿Por qué PDO recibe parámetros sin los dos puntos al usar consultas preparadas?

Tags: php, pdo

Como sabemos, cuando usamos PDO hay dos formas de preparar nuestras consultas: usando marcadores de posición `?`  o usando marcadores de nombre `:nombre`.

En la instrucción SQL, cuando se usan marcadores de nombre, cada nombre va precedido de los dos puntos (`:`). Por ejemplo:

`SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario_id=:id`

Luego, para pasar un valor relativo a `:id`, [el Manual muestra ejemplos parecidos a este](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

```
$stmt->bindValue(":id",$id);
```

o bien:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
```

o bien directamente como un array en el `execute`  :) :

```
$stmt->execute([":id"=>$id]);
```

Pero resulta que si no ponemos los dos puntos al pasar los parámetros, el código funciona exactamente igual.

Es decir, que si paso los parámetros así:

```
$stmt->bindValue("id",$id);
```

o así:

```
$stmt->bindParam("id",$id);
```

o así:

```
$stmt->execute(["id"=>$id]);
```

el código funciona exactamente igual y arroja los resultados esperados.

Aquí está la prueba: [`Ver código`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ya1m-etcb)

**¿Por qué PDO funciona sin los dos puntos al pasarle parámetros?**

Me extraña que el Manual no mencione nada al respecto. Incluso he leído en alguna parte que es mejor pasar los parámetros en sin usar los dos puntos.

Comment: Qué interesante pregunta. Veo una cuestión parecida en SOen con una [excelente respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925175/1983854)

Comment: Esta es una  pregunta curiosa. Creo que seria buena traducir la respuesta que indico @fedorqui, a menos que A. Cedano ya la este preparando.

Comment: después de leer en el meta que dejarías SOes, regresas con una excelente pregunta, valla sorpresa @A. Cedano

Comment: No estoy preparando nada @Kenny

Comment: Algunos comentarios, entre ellos el tuyo, me hicieron reconsiderar la decisión. Gracias @L.Ronquillo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## ¿Por qué funciona?

En el lenguaje PHP [se espera que los marcadores por nombre tengan dos puntos en la sentencia SQL](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), como lo indica la documentación oficial. [La documentación para `PDOStatement::bindParam()` indica que el parametro debe ser de la forma `:nombre` cuando se enlaza el parámetro al marcador](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindparam-parameters). Pero eso no es necesariamente cierto, por las siguientes razones.

No existe riesgo de ambigüedad cuando se enlazan los parámetros o se ejecuta la consulta porque el marcador en SQL debe tener dos puntos, una sola vez. Esto significa que el interprete de PHP puede hacer algunas suposiciones sin ningun riesgo. Si se ve [`pdo_sql_parser.c` en el código fuente de PHP, especificamente en la linea 90](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/323b2733f6b42d00dd86e77ac524d64f6ddc4e22/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c#L90), se puede observar la lista de caracteres validos en un marcador, que serian, alfanuméricos (digitos y letras), guiones bajos y los dos puntos. Un resumen corto de este archivo es que *solamente el primer caracter* puede ser el caractér dos puntos.

**En un ejemplo sencillo, `:nombre` es un marcador valido en el SQL, pero `nombre` y `::nombre` no lo son.**

Esto significa que, al momento indicar `bindParam()` o `execute()` el analizador puede asumir sin ningún riesgo que el parametro llamado `nombre` realmente debería ser `:nombre`. De manera que, podría simplemente añadir un `:` antes del resto de la palabra. De hecho, eso es exactamente lo que hace, en [`pdo_stmt.c`, empezando en la linea 362](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3.24/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L362) vemos:

```
if (param->name) {
    if (is_param && param->name[0] != ':') {
        char *temp = emalloc(++param->namelen + 1);
        temp[0] = ':';
        memmove(temp+1, param->name, param->namelen);
        param->name = temp;
    } else {
        param->name = estrndup(param->name, param->namelen);
    }
}
```

En un simple pseudocódigo, lo que esta función hace es lo siguiente:

```
SI el parametro tiene nombre ENTONCES
    SI el nombre del parámetro no empieza con ':' ENTONCES
        asignar una nueva cadena, 1 caractér mas largo que el nombre actual
        añadir ':' al comienzo de ese string
        copiar el resto del nombre del parámetro a la nueva cadena
        reemplazar la cadena antigua con la nueva
    EN OTRO CASO
        llamar a estrndup, que básicamente solo copia la cadena asi como esta
```

*Información extra de `estrndup` puede verse en [este enlace](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/Zend/zend_alloc.h#L173).

Asi que, `nombre` (en el contexto de `bindParam()` o `execute()`) se convierte en `:nombre`, lo cual concuerda con nuestro SQL, y se satisfacen los requerimientos de PDO.

---

P.D. La información se ha obtenido de [esta respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386469/pdo-prepared-statement-what-are-colons-in-parameter-names-used-for/38925175#38925175).