# ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estoy realizando una consulta a una base de datos mediante php, el caso es que me da

> error ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Y no sé cómo resolverlo. 
Si me pueden ayudar se lo agradezco.
La función que estoy ejecutando es:

```
function consultarCitasOcupadas($conexion, $dia, $usuario) {
    $consulta = "SELECT HORA,DNI_PACIENTE,FECHA FROM CITAS"
        . " WHERE (FECHA = TO_DATE(:dia,'DD/MM/YYYY')"
        . " AND USUARIO_MEDICO=:usuario"
        . " AND DNI_PACIENTE IS NOT NULL)"
        . " ORDER BY HORA";
    return $conexion->query($consulta);
}
```

Comment: Ray, ese es todo tu código? Te pregunto porque siempre que usas consultas parametrizadas tienes que enlazar la variables, ya sea una por una o en un arreglo, y has omitido completamente esta parte. Y otra pregunta, estas usando PDO, cierto?

Comment: Si ese es todo y si estoy usando PDO. ¿Qué es lo que falta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que te hace falta es enlazar las variables que estas incluyendo en tu consulta. A mi me gusta hacerlo con arreglos, porque me parece un poco mas simple y ordenado.

```
$arreglo_variables = [
        'dia' => $dia,
        'usuario' => $usuario
];
```

Entonces, al enlazar estas variables, puedes tener tu código de esta forma

```
function consultarCitasOcupadas($conexion, $dia, $usuario) {
    $arreglo_variables = [
            'dia' => $dia,
            'usuario' => $usuario
    ];
    $consulta = "SELECT HORA,DNI_PACIENTE,FECHA FROM CITAS"
        . " WHERE (FECHA = TO_DATE(:dia,'DD/MM/YYYY')"
        . " AND USUARIO_MEDICO=:usuario"
        . " AND DNI_PACIENTE IS NOT NULL)"
        . " ORDER BY HORA";
    return $conexion->query($consulta,$arreglo_variables);
}
```

Y así deberia funcionar bien y ya no verías el error.

---

*Para satisfacer tu curiosidad, hay información muy buena en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) acerca de como usar mejor PDO y evitar la inyección Sql, y tambien por si te preguntas porque no hay que poner los dos puntos en "dia" y "usuario" [esta pregunta de seguro te ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90081/por-qu%C3%A9-pdo-recibe-par%C3%A1metros-sin-los-dos-puntos-al-usar-consultas-preparadas/90114#90114).