# Ayuda con select basado en un criterio SQL, y postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

estoy intentando realizar una consulta con sql bajo un criterio

bueno les presento el codigo.

```
 include_once "conexion.php";
    /* Ejecuta una sentencia preparada pasando un array de valores */
    $id = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  Id = :Id";

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
if(!$statement){
     echo "ERROR:".PHP_EOL; 
     print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); 
}else{ 
    $statement->execute([':Id'=> 1]); 
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(); 
    var_dump($result); var_dump($statement); 
}
var_dump($result);
```

El resultado no me arroja nada,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al parecer no me regresa ningun valor, pero si lo intento con el criterio de nombre, este me devuelve el valor que espero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy sospechando que el problema esta en la condicion utilizando el **id**
ya que no me regresa nada.

Espero su ayuda gracias.

Le he removido las comillas simples al criterio sql pero siguen sin devolverme un valor.

Al probar el valor que recibo con var_dump este me devuelve esto:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

YA ESTA ACTUALIZADO LOS CODIGOS, Y AL PARECER SIGUE SIN FUNCIONAR

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\select2.php:19:
array (size=0)
  empty

C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\select2.php:19:
object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE  Id = :Id' (length=35)

C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\select2.php:21:
array (size=0)
  empty


1
```

Probe la recomendacion, agregando lo siguiente en el codigo.

Comment: Por qué le pones comillas simples a Id en tu consulta? Eso no es necesario

Comment: Estaba haciendo pruebas, AlfredoPaz pero aun removiendolas, no me funciona. no me devuelve ningun valor

Comment: Juan, el código debería funcionar como lo tienes. PDO coloca los dos puntos aquí: `$statement->execute(['id'=> 2]);` aunque tú no se los pongas ([ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90081/29967)). Sinceramente, lo único raro que veo es **el puntito verde al lado de la columna `Id`, en la imagen**. ¿No será que tienes dos tablas en dos lugares distintos? ¿Que la columna se llama de otro modo?... En todo caso, ¿qué imprime un `var_dump($result);`

Comment: Que tal, @A.Cedano el punto verde es para remarcar que la columna Id, se llama de esa manera. eh intentado de varias manera pero me sigue sin funcionar, no se si porque es postgresql tendria otra sintaxis

Comment: No tiene nada que ver que sea postgresql. Precisamente una de las mayores ventajas de PDO es poder usar código indistintamente en cualquiera de los manejadores de base de datos soportados. **¿El `var_dump($result);`  no muestra nada?**

Comment: ya actualize la pregunta con los cambios que mencionaste @A.Cedano actualiza

Comment: Juan, prueba escribiendo el nombre de la tabla con comillas de identificación (como está escrito ahora en el código... lo edité porque desde comentarios no podía mostrarte cómo sería). Lo único raro sería que estuviera confundiendo la tabla `users` con otra tabla del sistema... o que estés apuntando a otra base de datos, etc. De todos modos, sugiero que edites la pregunta, poniendo el código tal y como lo tienes, no sea que se te haya escapado algún detalle importante en las modificaciones, de ese modo podría revisarlo.

Comment: ya actualize la pregunar  @A.Cedano, le agregue las comillas simples y sigue sin devolver un valor.

Comment: Es muy extraño. Verifica si no hay algún error de este modo: `$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql); if(!$statement){ echo "ERROR:".PHP_EOL; print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); }else{ $statement->execute([':Id'=> 1]); $result = $statement->fetchAll(); var_dump($result); var_dump($statement); }` y comenta lo que obtienes en pantalla.

Comment: ya lo agregue @A.Cedano ya actualize la pregunta, y agregue el resultado.

Comment: Hay algo pero que muy raro e intrigante aquí. Yo sigo pensando en que la tabla `users` puede ser otra. Intenta sacar lo que hay en ella así:  `$strSQL="SELECT * FROM users"; $stmt = $pdo->query($strSQL); $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); var_dump($arrDatos);`  y revisa lo que arroja ese `var_dump`. A ver lo que hay en esa famosa tabla `users`...

Comment: Estoy utilizando una consulta preparada, al utilizar  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
   --WHERE Id = 1 
    ORDER BY name"; $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); $stmt->execute(); $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
 var_dump($arrDatos); ` y si me devuelve los valores. el problema al agregar un criterio con Id

Comment: Juan pero muestra aunque sea en un comentario un trozo del `var_dump` cuando devuelve datos... me gustaría saber cómo aparece la columna `Id` en ese `var_dump`. ¿Entre los datos que dices que devuelve hay **realmente** una columna llamada `Id` cuyo valor es `1`?

Comment: si @A.Cedano , hice una captura de los datos que tengo en mi tabla.. tengo un registro con el Id, y la columna que se llama Id

Comment: Juan me gustaría verlo en un `var_dump`, aunque sea un trozo de los registros.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo este ejemplo totalmente funcional para que te guíes y lo adaptes a tus necesidades

```
<?php 
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo", "root", "password");
    /* Ejecuta una sentencia preparada pasando un array de valores */
    $id = 2;
    $sql = "SELECT titulo FROM movies WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam('id', $id);
    $statement->execute();

    while($fila = $statement->fetch()){
        echo $fila["titulo"];
    }
```

> Como notas hago uso del método fetch, pero dentro del bucle while para
>   acceder a cada una de las claves/columnas de mi tabla directo de mi
>   base de datos.
>
> Otro detalle es que para indicar los valores que se van a usar
>   dinámicamente en la consulta hago uso de bindParam para indicarlo; de
>   tal modo que dejo al método execute sin argumentos

También como notas pase el valor 2 del id a una variable con lo cual también puedes pasar un valor dinámico de este modo `$statement->bindParam('id', $id);`

Comment: no me funciono Alfredo Paz, si utilizo otro criterio si me devuelve el valor menos el que espero

Comment: Seguro estás apuntando a la base de datos correcta?

Comment: Fijate @JuanL que tú Columna Id esté bien escrita

Comment: Alfredo Paz, agregue una imagen en el problema, mi  **Id** esta de esa forma. como lo tengo en la bd lo estoy apuntando en el sql

Comment: En el método execute agrégale al Id entre comillas dos puntos así :id

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  Id = :Id";   $statement->execute([':Id'=> 1]);, sin funcionar aun   Alfredo Paz