# Problemas con array en sentencia preparada

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statements

les cuento.

Desde un formulario, estoy recibiendo una serie de datos en un array:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
   (
      [Serie_maquina] => SERIE1234
      [Codigo_maquina] => 6078AA
      [Descripcion_maquina] => DETALLE01
      [Cantidad_maquina] => 3
   )

 [1] => Array
   (
      [Serie_maquina] => SERIE5678
      [Codigo_maquina] => 9090BB
      [Descripcion_maquina] => DETALLE02
      [Cantidad_maquina] => 7
   )
)
```

Buscando en internet, encontre una explicacion de como ejecutar un array en una sentencia preparada usando un foreach, pero el problema que solo me esta insertando el ultimo valor del array. Este es mi codigo de insercion:

```
$db = $this->dblocal;
$query = "INSERT INTO `detalle_maquina` (Serie_maquina, Codigo_maquina, Descripcion_maquina, Cantidad_maquina) VALUES (:serieMaquina, :codigoMaquina, :descripcionMaquina, :cantidadMaquina)";

foreach ($datosMaquina as $key => $value) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bindParam("serieMaquina",$value["Serie_maquina"]);
   $stmt->bindParam("codigoMaquina",$value["Codigo_maquina"]);
   $stmt->bindParam("descripcionMaquina",$value["Descripcion_maquina"]);
   $stmt->bindParam("cantidadMaquina",$value["Cantidad_maquina"]);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

No se que pueda estar realizando mal, trate dejando el prepare fuera del foreach y lo mismo. Si me pudiesen orientar, se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Encontre mi error, y es que estaba agregando el execute fuera del foreach, lo ingrese dentro y funciono altiro!

Answer (score 0):

Corregi mi error, debia meter el execute() dentro del foreach y listo, dejo como quedo arreglado por si a alguien le sirve.

```
$db = $this->dblocal;
$query = "INSERT INTO `detalle_maquina` (Serie_maquina, Codigo_maquina, Descripcion_maquina, Cantidad_maquina) VALUES (:serieMaquina, :codigoMaquina, :descripcionMaquina, :cantidadMaquina)";

foreach ($datosMaquina as $key => $value) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bindParam("serieMaquina",$value["Serie_maquina"]);
   $stmt->bindParam("codigoMaquina",$value["Codigo_maquina"]);
   $stmt->bindParam("descripcionMaquina",$value["Descripcion_maquina"]);
   $stmt->bindParam("cantidadMaquina",$value["Cantidad_maquina"]);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Aunque funcione (por lo que se explica en la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90081/29967)), conviene que uses los dos puntos `:` en el primer parámetro de  `bindParam`, porque es el estándar y porque al no hacerlo, obligas a PDO a hacerlo por ti. También, convendría usar transacciones para inserciones masivas (en bucles). Si la inserción falla en algún punto del bucle no será fácil saber más adelante cuáles registros se insertaron y cuáles no.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu recomendacion, tendre en cuenta esos cambios