# Tengo un problema a la hora de insertar un registro en mi base de datos

Tags: php, pdo, insert

Este es el formulario para agregar un nuevo registro, los datos solicitados son: nombre, Cédula de Identidad, edad, estado civil, dirección y país.

```
<form action='../administradores/administrar_profesor.php' method='post'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="autor">Cédula de Identidad</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CI" name="CI">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="edad">Edad</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="est_civil">Estado Civil</label>
                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="est_civil" name="est_civil"> -->
                    <select name="est_civil" id="est_civil" class="form-control">
                        <option disabled>Seleccionar</option>
                        <option value="Soltero">Soltero</option>
                        <option value="Casado">Casado</option>
                        <option value="Separado">Separado</option>
                        <option value="Viudo">Viúdo</option>
                        <option value="Concubino">Concubino</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pais">País</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pais" name="pais" >
                </div>
                <input type='hidden' name='insertar' value='insertar'>
                <a href="index.php"><input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Volver"></a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    
            </form>
```

Este es el archivo con el método insertar:

```
include_once '../config/conexion.php';

class CrudProfesores extends Database{

// constrctor
public function __construct()
{
}

// método para insertar un nuevo registro de un profesor

public function insertar($profesor)
{
    $db = Database::conectar();
    $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO profesores VALUES(:nombre, :CI, :edad, :est_civil, :direccion, :pais)');
    $insert->bindValue('nombre', $profesor->getNombre());
    $insert->bindValue('CI', $profesor->getCI());
    $insert->bindValue('edad', $profesor->getEdad());
    $insert->bindValue('est_civil', $profesor->getEst_civil());
    $insert->bindValue('direccion', $profesor->getDireccion());
    $insert->bindValue('pais', $profesor->getPais());
    $insert->execute();
}}
```

Este archivo verifica si el elemento insertar no viene nulo, llama al CRUD e inserta un nuevo profesor:

```
require_once '../crud/Profesores.class.php';
require_once '../datos/datosProfesores.php';

$obj_Profesores = new CrudProfesores();
$profesor = new DatosProfesores();

    // si el elemento insertar no viene nulo, llama al crud e inserta un nuevo profesor
    if(isset($_POST['insertar'])){
        $profesor->setNombre($_POST['nombre']);
        $profesor->setCI($_POST['CI']);
        $profesor->setEdad($_POST['edad']);
        $profesor->setEst_civil($_POST['est_civil']);
        $profesor->setDireccion($_POST['direccion']);
        $profesor->setPais($_POST['pais']);
        // llama a la función insertar definida en el crud
        $obj_Profesores->insertar($profesor);
       
        header('location:../vistas/ingresarProfesor.php');
    }else{
        echo 'Se há producido un error';
    }
```

El problema que tengo, es que cuando quiero insertar un nuevo registro, no inserta en la base de datos no lanza ningún error.

Verifiqué si era un problema de que no venían los datos del formulario pero no, creo que es con el método insertar.

Agradezco si logran solucionar mi problema

Comment: por que el listado de campos llevan ":" en cada campo?

Comment: Vi en un ejemplo, e intenté para ver si ese era el problema pero no funcionó.

Comment: ese insert le falta a que campo ira cada uno INSERT INTO profesores(nombre_campo1,nombre_campo2,etc..) VALUES(..) el nombre_campo se refiere al nombre del campo que tengas puesta en tu tabla donde ira insertado cada uno

Comment: Tienes que pasar un `bindValue` por cada parámetro que indiques en la consulta. En este caso no estás pasando nada para `:nombre`, por tanto tú consulta fallará.

Comment: Los 2 puntos es parte de la sintaxis válida @MauEspaña lee aqui https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: @MauEspaña el asunto de los dos puntos fue abordado en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90081/29967).

Answer (score -1):

Tendrias que colocarlo así:

```
$insert = $bd->prepare(“inserto into profesores (nombre, ci, edad, est_civil, dirección, país) values (‘”.$_POST['nombre'].”’,’”. $_POST['ci']. ”’,”. 
$_POST['edad']. ”,’”. $_POST['est_civil']. ”’,’”. $_POST['direccion']. ”’,’”. 
$_POST['pais'].”’);”;
```

y luego ejecutar tu consulta

Comment: Tu código va a fallar, revisa que comillas estás usando

Comment: Además del hecho que la vuelve insegura pues pasas directo los valores que el usuario manda, ahi estás desaprovechando todo el poder de PDO

Comment: Voto en contra de esta respuesta, porque hace involucionar el código original conduciendo a la **mala práctica** de cambiar consultas preparadas por consultas directas conteniendo variables, las cuales pueden ser manipuladas para inyectar código malicioso en el sistema (inyección SQL).

Comment: el problema era que me faltaban los campos de la tabla profesores en el INSERT

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos