# Por qué me dice que php que el método está indefinido?

Tags: php, php5

Tengo 2 scripts PHP. en el primero tengo la funcion *obtenerDepartamento* y en la segundo contiene una instancia de la clase estudiante y tengo la función *departamento*. Dentro de esta función hago referencia a la instancia creada previamente con global. A continuación dejo el código:

```
class estudiantes {

function obtenerDepartamento($id)
  {

    try {

      $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM departamentos WHERE id = :id");
      $query->execute(["id" => $id]);
      return $query->fetch();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo ('Ha ocurrido un error: ' . $e->getMessage());
      die('Línea del error: ' . $e->getLine());
    }
  }

}
```

Segundo script:

```
require_once('../../core/models/class.conexDB.php');
require_once('../../core/core_report.php');
require_once('../../core/models/class.estudiante.php');

require 'fpdf/rotation.php';
include '../reportegeneral/funciones_cert.php';


$detalleEstudiantes = new estudiantes();

function departamento($id)
{

  global $detalleEstudiantes;
  if ($row1 = $detalleEstudiantes->obtenerDepartamento()) {
    $departamento = $row1['detalle'];
  }
  return $departamento;
}
```

En el segundo script, php me indica que no hay ningún método *obtenerDepartamento* definido

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: No le estás pasando ningún parámetro al método cuando lo llamas. Por otra parte, ¿para que tienes esta linea?:
global $detalleEstudiantes;

Comment: ya le añadí el parámetro y sigue igual. Por otra parte, la línea global $detalleEstudiantes; me sirve para hacer referencia a la variable $detalleEstudiantes = new estudiantes();

Comment: ¿Puedes completar con el mensaje de error?

Comment: intenta poner la global antes de tu `$detalleEstudiantes = new estudiantes();`, es decir  `global $detalleEstudiantes; $detalleEstudiantes = new estudiantes();` y tambien veo el punto de @H.Díaz que no estas pasando valor en `$detalleEstudiantes->obtenerDepartamento()`

Comment: Esto es lo que me dice php

Comment: Undefined method 'obtenerDepartamento'.intelephense(1013)

Comment: @Artes acabo de hacer lo que me diiste y sigue igual

Comment: si estas importando correctamente los php?

Comment: ok, en ese caso, lo que veo es que necesitas enviar tu `$detalleEstudiantes` en la `function departamento($detalleEstudiantes, $id){}` y después llamarlo `departamento($detalleEstudiantes)`, ya que como `$detalleEstudiantes->obtenerDepartamento()` esta dentro de la funcion la variable no existe. Si quieres usar la global en otras funciones declarala fuera de la funcion, pero para invocar la clase es necesario que le pases el parametro de la global a la función.

Comment: Primeramente, el uso de `global` se considera casi siempre una mala práctica. ¿Qué justifica su uso aquí? Luego, no se ve el contexto desde el cual llamas a `departamento()`. Y, dentro de esa función, se ve que llamas a `obtenerDepartamento()` sin pasarle ningún parámetro, cuando en la clase se ve que ese método debe recibir un parámetro, supongo que la llamada debe hacerse así: `if ($row1 = $detalleEstudiantes->obtenerDepartamento($id)) {`. Finalmente, y como ya te han comentado más arriba, verifica que estás incluyendo los archivos correctamente.

Comment: La vinculación de parámetros, me parece que te faltan : , sería     
$query->execute([":id" => $id]);

Comment: @Juan funciona [aunque no se pongan los dos puntos en el nombre del  parámetro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90081/29967).

Comment: Mmmm. Veo que importas una clase class.estudiante.php ¿no habrá un error o un conflicto de nombres? Supongo que has corregido lo del argumento en la llamada a obtenerDepartamento.

Comment: El código y las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit] y añádiendo los errores y demás. Acá en los comentarios el código y los logs son casi ilegibles. Y tampoco se trata de que sea un chat. La respuesta a un comentario que pide aclaraciones debe ser una edición de la pregunta para añadir información.

Comment: ¿La clase estudiante esta completo en tu ejemplo? Podrías probar ```function obtenerDepartamento($id) { return $id; }``` y compruebas a ver si te devuelve el id o si persiste el mismo fallo, lo puedes comprobar asi ```var_dump($detalleEstudiantes->obtenerDepartamento($id));```

Answer (score 0):

Trata de instanciar la clase estudiante dentro del método de la siguiente manera:

```
function departamento($id){

    $detalleEstudiantes = new estudiantes();

    global $detalleEstudiantes;
    if ($row1 = $detalleEstudiantes->obtenerDepartamento()) {
        $departamento = $row1['detalle'];
    }
    return $departamento;
}
```