# problemas con segundo modal php

Tags: php, modal

Tengo una pagina con dos tablas, cada una dispone de un boton que activa un modal para insertar registro, en cuanto a la primera una vez hecho funciona correctamente. Pero una vez inserto la segunda tabla con el boton para activar el modal de insertar registro, abre el modal correctamente, tira los datos al backend correctamente me devuelve el mensaje de datos insertados pero no inserta ningún dato en la tabla. He revisado varias veces y no veo el porqué.
Pongo el codigo del segundo modal y del codigo php de insercion del registro en la tabla.

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="btn-text-right">
  <button type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modal-nuevacita">
    Nuevo Cita
  </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<form 
  action="../../app/controllers/reconocimientos/create_citarm.php"
  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-nuevacita">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#808000 ;color:white">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-nuevacita">Cita para Reconocimiento Medico</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" style="color: white;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Trabajador</label>
              <select name="trabajador_crm" id="" class="form-control">
```

```php
<?php foreach ($trabajadores as $trabajador) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $trabajador['id_trabajador']; ?>">
<?php echo $trabajador['nombre_tr'] ?> | <?php echo $trabajador['nombre_cat'] ?>
  </option>
<?php } ?>
```

```html
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Fecha cita</label>
                <input type="fecha_crm" name="fecha_rm" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Anotaciones / restricciones</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" name="anotaciones_crm" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-floppy"></i> Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--fin modal-->
```

---

```
<?php

include('../../../app/config.php');

$trabajador_crm = $_POST['trabajador_crm'];
$fecha_crm = $_POST['fecha_crm'];
$anotaciones_crm = $_POST['anotaciones_crm'];

$sentencia = $pdo->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO citas_rm 
     (trabajador_crm, fecha_crm, anotaciones_crm)
   VALUES
     (:id_trabajador, :fecha_crm, :anotaciones_crm)"
);

$sentencia->bindParam('trabajador_crm', $trabajador_crm);    
$sentencia->bindParam('fecha_crm', $fecha_crm);
$sentencia->bindParam('anotaciones_crm', $anotaciones_crm);

if ($sentencia->execute()) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Reconocimiento registrado correctamente";
  $_SESSION['icono'] = 'success';
  header('Location: ' . $URL . '/admin/reconocimientos');
} else {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Formacion NO creada";
  $_SESSION['icono'] = 'warning';
  header('Location: ' . $URL . '/admin/reconocimientos');
}


?>
```

Comment: disculpad por poner los dos codigos en la misma descripcion, no se como añadir dos codigo separados en stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el parámetro `trabajador_crm` no existe:

```
$sentencia->bindParam('trabajador_crm', $trabajador_crm);
```

Ten en cuenta que en `bindParam()`<sup>1</sup> no se ponen los nombres de las columnas, sino los nombres de los parámetros. Lo que se suele hacer, para evitar confusiones, es declarar cada parámetro como se llama la columna. Cosa que no has hecho aquí y de ahí la confusión.

Para corregirlo, pon el parámetro como lo has llamado en la consulta preparada:

```
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO citas_rm 
     (trabajador_crm, fecha_crm, anotaciones_crm)
   VALUES
     (:id_trabajador, :fecha_crm, :anotaciones_crm)"
);

$sentencia->bindParam(':id_trabajador', $trabajador_crm);    
$sentencia->bindParam(':fecha_crm', $fecha_crm);
$sentencia->bindParam(':anotaciones_crm', $anotaciones_crm);
```

O bien, nombra el parámetro como se llama la columna, que es la práctica habitual:

```
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO citas_rm 
     (trabajador_crm, fecha_crm, anotaciones_crm)
   VALUES
     (:trabajador_crm, :fecha_crm, :anotaciones_crm)"
);

$sentencia->bindParam(':trabajador_crm', $trabajador_crm);    
$sentencia->bindParam(':fecha_crm', $fecha_crm);
$sentencia->bindParam(':anotaciones_crm', $anotaciones_crm);
```

En ambos casos he puesto los `:` el invocar a `bindParam()`. Si no los pones funciona, pero es porque obligas al controlador a poner esos `:` que no pusiste<sup>2</sup>. Ayuda al controlador, ahorrándole trabajo suplementario.

Dicho eso, a tu código le falta madurez. No hay ningún control de errores. Y pasas a obtener variables que podrían no estar de manera directa, exponiéndote a casos de *`Undefined index`*. Deberías implementar bloques `try ... catch` para la ejecución de las consultas, y usar ternarios o fusión de null para recuperar los datos del `$_POST`, sometiendo a verificación aquellos valores de columnas declaradas del tipo `NOT NULL` sin un valor por defecto.

---

#### Notas

1. Para comprender cómo funciona `bindParam()` [ver la documentación en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php).
2. El asunto ya fue tratado en la pregunta: *[¿Por qué PDO recibe parámetros sin los dos puntos al usar consultas preparadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90081/29967)*.

Comment: GRACIAS, será que fue viernes y la cabeza ya no da para mas

Comment: como bien dices si observo que le falta y me falta madurez en el codigo, gracias por el comentario